# Model com propriedades de tipos dinamicos

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Eu tenho um select no banco que trás diversos itens e carrega tudo em uma model. A questão é que um dos itens, dependendo de como o select é feito, é trazido com tipo diferente.
Ex:

A propriedade no model:

```
public int procodigo { get; set; }
```

O conteudo a ser carregado nessa propriedade pode ser int ou decimal, dependendo da ação do cliente.

Eu poderia criar duas models, mas acredito que pode ser meio zuado isso.

Obrigado desde já!

Comment: Por que não usar apenas um decimal?

Comment: @EvandroSilva Porque por algum motivo na hora de colocar um numero inteiro dentro dele dá exception.

Comment: Só fazer um cast para decimal: `decimal x = (decimal)y`

Comment: @JuniorDias Qual Exception?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Essa exception:
"The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Int32' type to the 'System.Decimal' type is not valid."

Comment: Como ta sua tabela, porque não e boa pratica isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilize o `dynamic` C#.

```
public dynamic procodigo { get; set; }
```

Nesse caso, você não precisa se preocupar qual o tipo que será armazenado. Tanto `decimal` quanto `int` funcionaram perfeitamente.

Para mais informações veja [a documentação da msdn.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx)

Comment: Só uma observação: esta não é a melhor solução quando os dados precisam ser representados no EF ou um model para Tabela de um Banco de dados.

Comment: Bom, funcionou aqui, não conhecia esse dynamic. Obrigado!

@EvandroSilva ficarei atento a esse detalhe.